# python :zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check

Tags: python

[Emergent!]
when I use pip3 to install scipy,　I get this error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 577, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 810, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 649, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 842, in _download_http_url
    stream=True,
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 36, in send
    cached_response = self.controller.cached_request(request)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 102, in cached_request
    resp = self.serializer.loads(request, self.cache.get(cache_url))
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 108, in loads
    return getattr(self, "_loads_v{0}".format(ver))(request, data)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 164, in _loads_v2
    cached = json.loads(zlib.decompress(data).decode("utf8"))
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
```

I was use scipy.io.loadmat to load data,but it is also error with ' zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check'.
And I uninstall scipy,and use 'pip3 install scipy' to re-install scipy，but also get this error.
Does somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this github [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3359) the problem you are facing is due to a bug in the `cachecontrol` upstream library vendored by `pip` and not by `pip` itself. This should be [fixed](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/3382) if you upgrade `cachecontrol`.

Comment: It is ok when I upgrade cachecontrol. Thank you very much!